# Git pull from read-only remote fails

Tags: git, github

I have a clone of a forked private repository that I am attempting to setup a read-only remote for.

I run have run the following to get things setup:

Clone the repo.

```
git clone git@github.com:scottsuch/repo.git
```

Add the read-only upstream.

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/org-name/repo.git
```

Here is the output of `git remote -v show`

```
origin  git@github.com:scottsuch/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:scottsuch/repo.git (push)
upstream    git://github.com/org-name/repo.git (fetch)
upstream    git://github.com/org-name/repo.git (push)
```

Now if I attempt to pull in changes from upstream via `git pull upstream master` I get the following response:

```
fatal: remote error:
  Repository not found.
```

I'm fairly certain that this is a standard procedure and have seen many examples of this working. However I'm not sure if there is some permissions issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original repository is private, so you need to authenticate before you can access it. Your current remote URL is not configured for authentication, but for public access.

Change `git://github.com/org-name/repo.git` to either

- `git@github.com:org-name/repo.git` to use SSH keys, or
- `https://github.com/org-name/repo.git` to use password authentication over HTTPS

with the two commands

- `git remote set-url upstream <new-url>` and
- `git remote set-url --push upstream <new-url>`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something adding the git@ or https:// verion make the repo not read-only. I didn't clearly state in my original post that I'm trying to avoid accidentally pushing code to the upstream, hence the attempt at using the read-only URL.

The solution I came up with was to set the upstream via `git remote add upstream git@github.com:org/repo.git`, then break the push url with your example `git remote set-url --push upstream git://github.com/org/repo.git`. It works, but just feels clunky.

Comment: The `git@` and `https://` versions allow you to authenticate to GitHub, the first using SSH keys and the second using HTTP authentication. The target repository's permissions on GitHub will determine what you can and can't do. If the target repository is private, you will *have to authenticate* before you can `fetch` or `pull` from it. That's no different from GitHub's web UI; you need to log in before you can access private repositories.